# Displaying latest 10 images from file directory

Tags: php

I'm using this piece of php to pull the latest images from my directory, but I only want to display the latest 10 uploads instead of everything.

Anybody an idea how to alter the code so it does this? Thanks!

```
<?php
   $files = glob("images/*.*");
   for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++){

      $image = $files[$i];
      echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" id="lay"/>';
   }
?>
```

Comment: how do know what the "latest" 10 are you dont check dates or sort by date or ..

Comment: How do you define "latest" ? Have you tried a sort and and for going from 1 to 10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also this using [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
if($images = array_slice(glob("images/*.*")){
    //sort
    usort($images, create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);'));
    //loop 10
    foreach (array_slice($images, 0, 10) as $image) {
       echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="..."/>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to piece of code used in a project. and you can adjust this according to your requirement.

```
$folder = 'images/';
$filetype = '*.*';
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);
$count = count($files);

$sortedArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $sortedArray[date ('YmdHis', filemtime($files[$i]))] = $files[$i];
}

ksort($sortedArray);
echo '<table>';
foreach (array_slice($sortedArray), 0, 10) as &$filename) {
    #echo '<br>' . $filename;
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo '<a name="'.$filename.'" href="#'.$filename.'"><img src="'.$filename.'" /></a>';
    echo substr($filename,strlen($folder),strpos($filename, '.')-strlen($folder));
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

and if you want to have the newest images at the top instead of at the bottom, then change this line:

```
ksort($sortedArray);
```

to this:

```
krsort($sortedArray);
```

**Update apply the limit:**

To apply the limit, you can simply apply counter or array slice function under final foreach and get top of your images.

Answer (score 0):

I like the `foreach` and `array_slice` but here in an alternate:

```
array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', $files=glob("images/*.*")), SORT_DESC, $files);

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get last 10
$limit = 10;
$arr = glob('/dir/dir/*.{jpg,jpeg,JPG,JPEG}', GLOB_NOESCAPE|GLOB_BRACE);
return array_slice($arr, (count($arr)-$limit), $limit);
```